# C - problem with const - error: initializer element is not constant

Tags: c, declaration, linkage, constant-expression, storage-duration

I try add global variable in my `buttons.c` file, but have a error - `initializer element is not constant`. Example `headers.h` file

```
struct MainStruct {
  GtkEntryBuffer *buffer;
  GtkWidget *entry;
  GtkWidget *label;
};

extern struct MainStruct *p;
extern const char *text_entry;
void lower_button_clicked(GtkWidget *lowerbutton);
```

and when file **main.c** calls file **buttons.c**, I cannot define the variable `text_entry`. What am I doing wrong?

**buttons.c**

```
#include <gtk/gtk.h>
#include "headers.h"

const char *text_entry = gtk_entry_buffer_get_text(p -> buffer); // is not constant, why?
void lower_button_clicked(GtkWidget *lowerbutton)
{
  printf("%s\n", text_entry);
}
```

I saw a lot of similar questions that talk about **static**, but

```
static const char *text_entry = gtk_entry_buffer_get_text(p -> buffer);
```

not working.
How do I define this variable to be global? to avoid duplication in similar functions

Comment: I think you're going about this the wrong way.  Your goal should be to make your variables *local,* not global.

Comment: @RobertHarvey, Why? I have 5 functions and in them all the same variables are defined, which duplicates the code

Comment: For the same reasons that global variables have always been bad; they're difficult to reason about.  You never know when, why and by whom the variable has been  changed.

Comment: @karaname You may not initialize a variable with the static storage duration with a non-constant expression. Also it is a bad idea when function definitions depend on a global variable.

Comment: @VladfromMoscow, okay, if I define a **#define text_entry** in header and I will use it in the file ```buttons.c``` it will be better this way?

Comment: You cannot use the return value of a function to **initialize** a variable, but you can **assign a value** to it from any function. When do you expect the function `gtk_entry_buffer_get_text` to be called? I guess it must be called repeatedly, so you might want to put the code that would be duplicated in a separate function that can be called from your 5 functions. For example you could have a function like `const char *my_get_text(struct some_structure *p) { return gtk_entry_buffer_get_text(p -> buffer); }`

Comment: @Bodo, good idea, thanks!

Comment: @karaname No, it will not be better.

Comment: @VladfromMoscow, thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the C Standard (6.7.9 Initialization)

> 4 All the expressions in an initializer for an object that has static
>   or thread storage duration shall be constant expressions or string
>   literals.

And in this declaration

```
const char *text_entry = gtk_entry_buffer_get_text(p -> buffer);
```

the initializer is not a constant expression. So the compiler issues an error.

Also pay attention to that these declarations

```
extern const char *text_entry;
```

and that follows it

```
static const char *text_entry = /*...*/;
```

contradict each other. The first declaration declares  the variable text_entry as having external linkage while the second declaration declares the variable as having internal linkage.